# Не работает метод pyautogui.press() из библиотеки pyautogui при открытом окне приложения

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

Написал простенький скрипт который должен постоянно нажимать одну и ту же клавишу, запускаю скрипт, клацаю на блокнот и в нем все работает, то есть клавиша печатает  `1` как и положено, как только разворачиваю приложение(игру), действие что закреплено за нажатием `1` не работает, программа при это не прекращает работу, пожалуйста укажите что я упусти

```
import pyautogui
import time

Timer = 0
while True:
    pyautogui.press('1')
    Timer += 1
    print('Время прошло: ', Timer, ' c','\n\n')
    time.sleep(1)
```